# How can I write unit test for Telegram bot in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, telegram

I wrote the telegram bot, and it works perfectly, BUT I still didn't understand how can I write the unit test for this? I mean I have to make a fake messages from my bot. I realized that I need to use moq instead real telegramm bot client. But I still didn't understand how exactly it may look like?

Here is my method, I want UnitTesting:

```
   private readonly string _token = "<token value>";
   private ITelegramBotClient _client;

    public async void Comunicate()
    {
        _client = new TelegramBotClient(_token);
        var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
        {
            AllowedUpdates = { }
        };

        _client.StartReceiving(HandleUpdateAsync, HandleErrorAsync, receiverOptions, cancellationToken: _cts.Token);
        var me = await _client.GetMeAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");
        Console.ReadLine();

        async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (update.Type != UpdateType.Message)
                return;
            if (update.Message!.Type != MessageType.Text)
                return;
            var chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;

            var messageText = update.Message.Text;
            

            // here messages processed, I want to process fake messages without telegramm API using
            string valuteCode = "";
            string requredDate = "";
            BotActions botActions = ProcessTextMessage(messageText, ref  valuteCode, ref requredDate);
            string replyMessage = GetReply(botActions, requredDate, valuteCode);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");
            Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                chatId: chatId,
                text: replyMessage,
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        Task HandleErrorAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var ErrorMessage = exception switch
            {
                ApiRequestException apiRequestException
                    => $"Telegram API Error:\n[{apiRequestException.ErrorCode}]\n{apiRequestException.Message}",
                _ => exception.ToString()
            };

            Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

In Unit test I just have to call method Comunicate() and send ho handler fake testing messages without real messages sending in telegram. Unfortunatelly I don't understand how to do it. I know that I can create another bot just for testing this one but this not the way I want to go.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I would start by reducing complexity of this method and then test each part separately. There are too many paths this code can take to give a nice simple answer to your question. Ask yourself what it is that you want to assert (not just "that the method works"). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! Probably I wrote it not enought clear I want to test correct reply of my bot. But to get reply i have to text my bot manually. And I want to do automatically using unit test. Best regards.